# Disable UITableViewCellAccessory

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview

I want to disable the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosure` button for certain rows in my table. I cannot seem to find any way to do this. I tried just doing:

```
 cell.UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton.enabled = NO;
```

But no luck. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I have the same question. I'll let you know if anything turns up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the `enabled` property that you seek.  What you want to do is specify that there should be no accessory detail disclosure when you build the `UITableViewCell` objects.

So, in your `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, just set:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

and that will get rid of the accessory for that cell.